# How do I split a string using linq and C#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to split and parse a string using Linq. How do I extract VID and PID from this string?

```
HID\VID_0483&PID_5750\6&28E7587C&0&0000
```

Here is my code so far:

```
var vendorId = UsbSetting.Instance.UsbDeviceInfo.PnpDeviceId.Split('\\').Select(s=> s.Split('&'));
```

Comment: Regex seems to fits better into the problem.

Comment: @JosephCenk: "Want to split and parse string using Linq". But String.Split() isn't LINQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using below to parse
string s1 =@"HID\VID_0483&PID_5750\6&28E7587C&0&0000";

```
var vendorId = UsbSetting.Instance.UsbDeviceInfo.PnpDeviceId.Split('\\', '&').
                        SingleOrDefault((s) => s.Contains(UsbInfo.Vid.Description()))?.
                        Replace(UsbInfo.Vid.Description()+"_", ""); 

var productId = UsbSetting.Instance.UsbDeviceInfo.PnpDeviceId.Split('\\', '&').
                        SingleOrDefault((s) => s.Contains(UsbInfo.Pid.Description()))?.
                        Replace(UsbInfo.Pid.Description() + "_", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string s1 = @"HID\VID_0483&PID_5750\6&28E7587C&0&0000";
var split = s1.Split('\\','&');
string vendorID = split[1];
string productID = split[2];
```

Comment: I'm sorry, which part is LINQ?

Comment: Who cares. My answer solves the problem. Next somebody will ask how to assign "1" to an integer with Linq... If all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail.

Answer (score 0):

Regex grouping is quite useful in this case:

```
//group VID or PID followed by _ and 4 digits
string pattern = @"(\bVID|\bPID)_(\d{4})"; 
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
string vendorID = matches[0].Groups[2].Value;
string productID = matches[1].Groups[2].Value;
```